Function with normal distributed input parameters
I have the following situation:
There is a function $f(x.y.z)$
Case 1: $x,y,z$ are normally distributed  $\rightarrow f(x,y,z)$ is normally distributed
Case 2: $x,y,z$ are uniform distributed with $(-3\sigma,+3\sigma) \rightarrow f(x,y,z)$ is normal distributed.
Question: Is it possible to compare the standard deviations of $f(x,y,z)$ in case1 and case 2?
Or do I need more info about $f()$?
